# JQuery not acting as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a "drop down" menu where you click a div and the sibling below it will become visible or disappear. It should be extremely simple, but it is giving me trouble for some reason.

```
$(".dropDownClick").click(function(){
    alert($(self));
    $(self).next().css("display",(node.css("display")=="inline")?"none":"inline");
});
```

This code returns [object Object] and then doesn't change the display css of the next sibling. After a bit of testing I found that `$(self).next();` will actually break the code (if I try to do something like `alert($(self).next());` the code will not execute). I am assuming this is because there is no next sibling? But my HTML would suggest otherwise:

```
<div class="dropDownClick"><h1>Drop</h1></div>
<div class="dropDown" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Shouldn't the div with the class "dropDown" be selected when I call .next()?

Comment: Where did `node` come from?

Comment: Can you provide the jsFiddle of your Code?

Comment: `self` is `window` in context you are showing using it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be `this` not self, also you can use .toggle() instead of manually applying the display value

```
$(".dropDownClick").click(function () {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is a special variable, which is always available - but `self`/`node` are custom variables which has to be declared before using else it will throw a [reference error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wbd3V/)

Comment: That's it. Wow. That explains why it was so hard to Google for help. Could you possibly explain whats the difference between self and this?

Comment: _"there is no `self`"_ - [Yes there is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.self).

Comment: Thanks. I guess I just got some code I read mixed up considering I am not the strongest in JQuery. (Best Answer once it lets me by the way)

Comment: @nnnnnn oh so it is referring to window.self. That makes sense. Thanks!